# Jenkins job after merge request is created

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Gitlab for source control and Jenkins for build management.

I want to create a job in Jenkins that will run after a merge request is created. It is currently failing due to:

> ERROR: Branch not suitable for integration as it does not merge cleanly: Command "git merge --ff a83f5745ba2ca0586as4cfdb7d5e207a911d34" returned status code 128:
>
> stdout:
>
> stderr:
>
> *** Please tell me who you are.

In Jenkins job configuration (Which is Pipeline) I have the following:

```
Build Triggers
  Build when a change is pushed to GitLab. GitLab CI Service URL: http://...

  (*)Opened Merge Request Events    
  (*)Rebuild open Merge Requests: On push to source or target branch

Pipeline
  Pipeline script from SCM
    SCM: Git
      Repositories
        Repository URL: http://...
        Credentials: Jenkins
        Repository URL: ${gitlabSourceRepoSshUrl}
        Credentials: Jenkins
      Branches to build
        Branch Specifier (blank for 'any'): origin/${gitlabSourceBranch}
        Branch Specifier (blank for 'any'): merge-requests/${gitlabMergeRequestIid}
  Additional Behaviours
    (*)Wipe out repository and force clone
    (*)Merge before build
        Name of repository: origin
        Branch to merge: ${gitlabTargetBranch}
        Merge strategy: default
        Fast-forward mode: --ff

  Script Path: Jenkinsfile
```

In my Jenkins file, I have the following related section:

```
stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.isMergeRequest = env.gitlabTargetBranch != env.gitlabSourceBranch

                    deleteDir()
                    unstash 'src'

                    def javaHome = tool 'Java8'
                    def mvnHome = tool 'Maven3'
                }

                catchError {
                    withEnv(["PATH+JDK=$javaHome/bin:$mvnHome/bin", "JAVA_HOME=$javaHome"]) {
                        echo "branchName: ${env.branchName}; isMergeRequest: ${env.isMergeRequest}"
                        script {
                            if ((env.isMergeRequest != 'true')) {
                                echo "Executing tests for merge request..."
                                sh "./gradlew -Ddocker.local=true test"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                fileOperations([fileZipOperation('dockerLogs')])

                archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: 'dockerLogs.zip'

                echo "Gathering test reports"

                junit healthScaleFactor: 10.0, testResults: '**/build/test-results/test/*.xml'
            }
        }
```

Happy to provide any other info if needed!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your Git configuration lacks `user.name` and/or `user.email`. Perhaps, try setting these, globally, locally, or temporarily.

Globally:

```
git config --global user.name 'Foo Bar'
git config --global user.email foo@bar.baz
```

Locally (just for the current repo):

```
git config user.name 'Foo Bar'
git config user.email foo@bar.baz
```

Temporarily (just for the current run -- not sure how this fits in Jenkins):

```
git -c user.name='Foo Bar' <command>
git -c user.email=foo@bar.baz <command>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that I rebase my branch with upstream's target branch, then push with force. It works.

```
git checkout mybranch
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/targetbranch
git push -u origin +mybranch
```